# Server side analytics

Tags: web-analytics-tools

Anyone know any server side analytics tools?

I've heard of awstats, webalizer, and urchin. The last of which is expensive.

Are awstats/webalizer really the only free tools out there? It seems like there's an incredible hole in the analytics market, which the clientside market so saturated and the server side... not.

Suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, these are your options.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_analytics_software

Comment: That list isn't just server side analytics. The list is severely lacking if that's all that exists... and I know at least a few that aren't on there.

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://piwik.org/. It's a PHP/MySQL based system you can install on your own server and then embed the tags as you would do with Google Analytics. The difference is that the data is sent to your own servers and not Google's.

Found it off another post here (can't find the link to it now though).